# Error using np.vectorize inside a function

Tags: python, python-3.x, vectorization

I am trying to create a function called function2 that vectorize a function, it works when I only create one function, but if try to wrap it in another function I dont get the results that I need

this code works

```
A= np.array([1])
B= np.array([2])

def function1(a, b):
    if a > b:
        return a - b
    else:
        return a + b
function1 = np.vectorize(function1)

function1(A, B)

out array([3])
```

but this one does not and I dont know why, I am expecting to get the same result as the code above array([3])

```
def function1(a, b):
    if a > b:
        return a - b
    else:
        return a + b

def function2(a, b):
    function2 = np.vectorize(function1)
    return function2

function2(A, B)

out <numpy.vectorize at 0x24f0a22eba8>
```

thanks for the help in advance

Comment: because `function2` returns `function2`, which is just the result of `np.vectorize(function10`, which is just a function...

Comment: In *any* case, why are you using `np.vectorize` at all?

Comment: Updated my answer, let me know if you understand the issue here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because in the second case you are not calling the function you are just returning the function object. `np.vectorise` returns the function object but doesn’t call it.

Change your code to -

```
def function3(a, b):
    function2 = np.vectorize(function1)
    return function2(a,b) #call here

function3(A,B)
```

Should work now.

- In the first case function2 is the vectorised function object itself and passing (A,B) parameters to it will call it.
- In second case function2 is a parametric function but instead of using the parameters a,b it simple returns a function object. So when you call it with parameters, it overwrites  function2 and returns a vectorised function object each time, completely ignoring the parameters all together.
- In the third case (my solution) you are calling function3 which takes A,B parameters and first vectorises function1. Next it calls this vectorised function with the passed parameters and returns the output.

Follow the function calls and the sequential lines of code in your function and it will be super clear of why that is happening.